# Batch Query in FQL to get User Likes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using the following FQL query to get the 'likes' of a batch of users.
https://graph.facebook.com/fql&q=SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (user_id1,user_id2,user_id3,etc....).

What is the maximum number of user ids that i can pass with this FQl query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit on UIDs. The limit is on the time taken to run the query. So, running it with a small number of users who happen to have lots of likes will timeout, just as running it for many uids with few likes each.

I suggest chunking up the requests into 10-15 UIDs per query. Then using the Facebook Batch API to execute multiple querys at the same time.